# How to inject path to resources in springboot test

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've got a class that write files on the disk. Path to directory is injected using `@Value("${write.directory}")` that is set in application.yml file. What value should I set in application.yml file in test directory so that files are temporarily saved in resource files? Or is there a way to mock `Files.write(path, file)`?

Comment: What test and mock framework do you use?

Comment: Junit and mockito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JUnit [TemporaryFolder Rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) (Junit4) or JUnit 5's Temporary Directory([@TempDir](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html)) depending on the testing dependency you use.

Both allow the creation of files and folders that should be deleted when the test method finishes (whether it passes or fails).

Answer (score 1):

So in spring boot you can have different properties files for different environments, on the same lines you can have a separate application.yaml config for your tests and set the value of 'write.directory' to a temporary directory.

Another thing you can use is Java's 'Files.write' method to write to a specific path.

You can follow these steps to achieve what you want:

**1. Create a separate application.yaml for testing**

```
write:
  directory: ${java.io.tmpdir}/test-write-directory
```

**2. Use 'write.directory' in your test class**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml") // Use the correct file name if different
public class YourTestClass {

    @Value("${write.directory}")
    private String writeDirectory;

    @Test
    public void yourTest() {
        // Your test logic here
        // You can use the value of writeDirectory to construct paths for writing files
    }
}
```

**3. Mocking 'Files.write':**
you can use libraries like Mockito for such use case

Example

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@SpringBootTest
public class YourTestClass {

    @Value("${write.directory}")
    private String writeDirectory;

    @Mock
    private Files filesMock;

    @Test
    public void yourTest() {
        // Your test logic here

        // Mocking Files.write
        Path path = Path.of(writeDirectory, "test-file.txt");
        Files.write(path, "test content".getBytes());

        // Verify that Files.write was called
        verify(filesMock).write(path, "test content".getBytes());
    }
}
```

> Let me know if this helped your case and keep coding.

Comment: Such an easy explanation. Worked for me, thanks

Comment: `Files.write` is a static method, I knew it needed special approach. Have you checked this actually?

Comment: yes i have tried it myself, just add IOException in message signature and it will work like a charm